# Alternative way to show UIView instead of .XIB

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Is there an alternative way to show UIView instead of using .XIB? Because I have many UIViewControllers that I was showing it as `presentView` and now I have to change it.

My Code:

```
@IBAction func basketClearButton(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let basketClearView = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("clearBasket") as! ClearBasketViewController

    //self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    self.view.addSubview(basketClearView)
}
```

Comment: kindly elaborate your question a little, it is not clear what you want to achieve

Comment: @Usama83 I have `ViewControllers` and I'm presenting them. Now I would like to show them like a subView in Fade but how I would do that without using .XIB? Regards.

Comment: if i have understood correctly, you have some VCs which you were presenting but now you want to show the content of those view controller on the screen with some fade. right?

Comment: Yes, thats right. @Usama83

Comment: 'basketClearView' is a VC, it can not be added using addSubview. it will give you error

Comment: only way to add another VC's view as a subview is by making it child VC

Comment: Yes, I'm getting an error as I mentioned to you below but I think you didnt't see my message. I will try to ass child VC

Answer (score 0):

you can make those view controllers child of the VC you want to present them on [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html), by making one view controller child of another, you can add view of child VC as a subview to the view of parent VC

in that way you can show them on the same screen and whole of your previous code will stay as it is, only presenting logic will change

This can also be helpful [tutorial](http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers)

Comment: Thank you for your help but I don't want to use a container view. I will see how to call the chil

Answer (score 0):

Anything you can do in a .xib file, you can also do in code. So, if you have a view controller whose view you wish to add to the display without creating a .xib file for it, you can simply edit the view's content programmatically (for example, [self.view addSubview:someImageViewYouCreated];).

In the main view controller (or any other view controller in which you want to display the other view's content, you can just add the view from the new view controller. If, for example, the view controller you wish to add to the display is called SecondViewController, you'd write:

```
SecondViewController *newView = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:newView.view];
```

If you want to add the view with a fade in animation, you can do something like this:

```
   newView.view.alpha = 0.0;
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
      newView.view.alpha = 1.0;
   }];
```

Comment: i think we can not add another VC's view directly as a subview, first we have to make it child VC

Comment: @Usama83 Yes, you are right. I have added my code which gives me an error "Cannot invoke 'addSubView' "